# How do I get data from an XML API using C#

Tags: c#, xml

Hey I have never worked with xml so forgive my newbness but I can usually hit a api and deserialize JSON no problem.

This API however only returns XML so I am not sure what I need to do differently?

```
            string trendLogins = "dummpyAPIURL";
            string trendArgs = "myarguments";

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(trendLogins);

            // Add an Accept header for XML format.
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
            new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));

            // List data response.
            HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(trendArgs).Result;  // Blocking call! Program will wait here until a response is received or a timeout occurs.
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                // Parse the response body.
                var dataObjects = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<AggregatedTrendData>>().Result;  //Make sure to add a reference to System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll
                foreach (var d in dataObjects)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}", d.employeeID);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", (int)response.StatusCode, response.ReasonPhrase);
            }
```

Comment: Use XDocument and Linq to parse it. It's not deserialization as such, just parsing.

Comment: As @jtpalmerca already suggested **LINQ to XML** API is a way to go. It has `XDocument`, `XElement`, etc. It has everything what you need to handle XML.